# Unable to replace single backslashs in HTML5 drop file path -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I am building an electron app. When a user drop a file in electron app it have to show full file url.

```
           var arr = [];
           holder.ondrop = (e) => {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var path = e.dataTransfer.files[0].path;
                 arr.push(path);
           }
           console.log(arr[0]); // results C:electronelectron-quick-startmenu.png
```

Above code is working fine but path variable consists single backslashes `C:\electron\electron-quick-start\menu.png` .

When I try to use path variable it results `C:electronelectron-quick-startmenu.png` escaping backslashes.

I tried to replace single backslashes with double as shown below but it still resulting the string with empty slashes.

```
                path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
                        or
                path.replace("\\/", "/");
                        or                        
         path.replace(String.fromCharCode(92),String.fromCharCode(92,92));
```

Comment: "When I try to use path variable" — In what way are you trying to use it that results in that effect? You need to provide a real [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem. Your little snippet doesn't.

Comment: "I tried to replace single backslashes with double" — That's probably not the right approach to the problem, but since you didn't show us how you did that either, we can't tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: @Quentin edited my question could you check it.